# Not able to prevent the url back to login page if it's already in home page

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux, react-router, redux-toolkit

I have created a login page using RTK query, and i have an Route of login and home page
I have created a protected route  based on the IsAuthenticated prop
and wrapped protected route for home page and added a callback onLogin={handleLogin}

But the error says Login is not  component

`Login.js

```
const [loginUser, { data, isLoading, isError }] = useLoginUserMutation();
useEffect(() => {
if (data?.response === "true" && data?.state === "success"){
setErrorMsg("");
setEmail("");
setPassword("");
setIsAuthenticated(true);
navigate("/home", { state: { user: data?.user } });
}
else if (data?.response === "false" && data.state === "error"){
  setErrorMsg(true);
}
  else{
    setErrorMsg(false)
  }
}, [data,isError,isLoading]);

const handleLogin = async (e) => {
e.preventDefault();
console.log("****")
await loginUser({email,password})

}
```

App.js

```
function App() {

const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false);
const handleLogin = () => {
setIsAuthenticated(true);
}

return (
<div className="App">
  <Router>
    <Routes>
      <Route exact path="/">
        <Login onLogin={handleLogin} />
      </Route>
      <ProtectedRoute path="/home" component={Home} isAuthenticated={isAuthenticated}/>
    </Routes>
  </Router>
</div>
);
}
export default App;
```

ProtectedRoute.js

```
 import React from "react";
 import { Route, Navigate } from "react-router-dom";

 const ProtectedRoute = ({ isAuthenticated}) => {
 return isAuthenticated? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/" />;
 }

 export default ProtectedRoute;`
```

I have tried adding the protectedRoute and unable to consume isAutheticated value from Login.js
i used protected route to prevent back from login to home or vise versa

Comment: The `Login` component should be rendered by `Route`, e.g. `<Route path="/" element={<Login onLogin={handleLogin} />} />`. See the marked duplicate for addressing the route protection issue.

Comment: @Drew Reese But the I need to pass is Authenticated  value to check that right,That is not helping me with the solution

Comment: Normally you'd store the authentication state in a context or global app state, but passing `isAuthenticated` down as a prop from `App` to `ProtectedRoute` should work.

Comment: should i use Local Storage to get isAuthenticated value in the protected Route?

Comment: `isAuthenticated` is already passed as a prop to `ProtectedRoute`.

Comment: Still the error

Comment: What error are you referring to? If there's more to any issue you are facing can you [edit] the post to include all relevant details, including errors and any code stacktraces? This may include updating to share a more complete [mcve].

Comment: const ProtectedRoute = ({ isAuthenticated, component: Component, ...rest }) => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(props) =>
        isAuthenticated ? (
          <Outlet />
        ) : (
          <navigate to="/" replace />
        )
      }
    />
  );
};

Comment: is this fine i have updated the protected Route

Comment: No, `navigate` is a function, not a React component.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252879/discussion-between-r9102-and-drew-reese).

Comment: I have update the question

here is my protected Route

import React from "react";
import { Route, Navigate,Outlet  } from "react-router-dom";

const ProtectedRoute = ({ isAuthenticated, component: Component, ...rest }) => {
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(props) =>
        isAuthenticated ? (
          <Outlet />
        ) : (
          <Navigate to="/" replace />
        )
      }
    />
  );
};

export default ProtectedRoute;